# how to format django models?

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble understanding the formatting of django, my project is this, can anyone help me ?? I would like the Admin to have the function of the user inserting the images there. Thank you.

HOME:

```
{% for picture in photos %}
          <div><img> src="{{picture.pic}}"</img></div>
{% endfor %}
```

MODELS:

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.pic
```

VIEWS:

```
...
picture = Photos.objects.all()        
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'photos':picture})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please modify question accordingly to [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: What does this have to do with "formatting"?

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
  <div><img> src="{{picture.pic}}"</img></div>
```

to

```
  <div><img> src="{{picture.pic.url}}"</img></div>
```